# how to speed up recursive method to under one second?

Tags: java, performance, recursion

I have to solve a task with recursion, and the code has to run in under one second on an average computer. We are not allowed to use for/while loops and streams. We are allowed to use supporting methods and variables.

I already solved the recursion part of the task, my method works for all -111 < n < 131.
I am not sure how to speed up the process tho. Ive already tried it with an array and saved the values in it, but I don't think we are allowed to solve the task like that, since everything should be solved recursively..

How do I speed up this recursive method, especially for values n>30?

```
public static long sequence(int n, int a, int b, int c) {
   if (n > -111 && n < 131) {
      if(n==0) {
         return a;
      }
      if(n==1) {
         return b;
      }
      if(n==2) {
         return c;
      }
      if (n < 0) {
         return 2 * sequence(-n, a, b, c);
      } else {
         return sequence(n - 1, a, b, c) - sequence(n - 2, a, b, c) + 2 * sequence(n - 3, a, b, c);
      }
   }
   return 0L;
}
```

Comment: "Ive already tried it with an array and saved the values in it, but I don't think we are allowed to solve the task like that" - you were moving in the proper direction. The task definition as you presented it prohibits loops but not speed/memory tradeoff, so memorization is the answer. Just keep in mind: you probably don't need to memorize the computations for all `n`s - each call to `sequence` depends on the 3 most recent values only (but any memorization impl. would be ok for the 1st iteration)...

Comment: Cache results of a calculation and only compute if no value exists. You can use a `ConcurrentSkipListMap` and the `computeifAbsent` function. If you use a regular `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Look up and try to implement [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

It's a technique to cache the result of a computation (especially useful if it's expensive one) and reuse this result when the same input appears again. Currently you recalculate the result for the same input `n` every time it appears.

Hints: You can use [Map<Integer, Long>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), where key will be `n` and value is computed result. Or `long[]` can work as well, where value at index `n` will be computed result, you can use second array for negative `n`s.